Relationship between two adverbs modifying the same verb
If 2 adverbs of time are modifying the same verb, how do these adverbs affect each other in meaning?
For example:
“After their defeat in the match, they will be victorious in a few matches”
Do the adverbs “After their defeat in the match” and “in a few matches” (who modify the same verb) affect each other semantically? And in what ways?

Those are modifiers, not adverbs. Phrases get grammatical roles, not parts of speech like single words do.

What you mean is adverbial phrases. I would say these do not affect each other syntactically.

When is "the match"? Are you talking about a match that's already taken place? It's possible that if you were referring to a specific future match, the reference would be different - but we can't possibly know that with the information given. It's also worth noting that "in a few matches" could refer to a sequence/set of matches they're victorious in (cf "They were victorious in their matches against Spurs"), or a point in time (after a few earlier matches). If you want to be less ambiguous, add specific time phrases.

I'd suggest a better example. Perhaps 'After this unexpected defeat, they remained unbeaten for twelve weeks.' Two temporal phrases. The timeline is crystal clear; a punctive event followed by a 12-week period involving further matches. And swapping 'before' for 'after' obviously postposes the punctive event (the defeat).

@EdwinAshworth I see, but is the answer I got down correct? From what I understand, clauses must have a verb and subject, yet the example I gave doesn’t have it. What do you think? And thanks!

'Affect each other' is not a helpful turn of phrase here; 'affect each other semantically' probably defaults to 'change the meaning of'.  I suppose 'in a few matches' is polysemous, meaning '[winning] a few matches' or 'in a few matches' time', but I didn't even spot the second sense I mention on earlier readings. As I said, the example is somewhat unnatural, so interpretation has another level of complication. // Your asking about clauses seems very much at variance with the request 'Do the 'adverbs' [sic]  affect each other semantically?'

@EdwinAshworth I see, the example I gave has a structure similar to a translation of an old text (which mainly focused on time rather than “matches”, so that’s why it might not sound very natural, sorry. The exact sentence was something like: “After the defeat of the Sumerians, they will he victorious in 15 years”, does” my question mainly pertains to when the period is supposed to start, from the utterance or from the moment of defeat. As for the clause thing, it mainly refers to a respond I got down, which I’m conflated about, cause I’m not sure what “clauses” are supposed to mean here

The original would be better translated as 'The Sumerians were defeated in this battle. But they were to defeat the [Akkadians?] 15 years later.' And yes, the '15 years later' obviously refers to the [year of the] battle, as with say 1703 / 1718.

@EdwinAshworth I see, so we start from the moment of defeat, got it! Can you explain why? Thanks

There's an implicit 'from/at the time just mentioned/defined/implied' in the use of temporal expressions like 'in the few months before', '7 years later', 'for seven years [when used this way]', 'present / then / now' (as in 'the then Chancellor'), 'for the following year' ... and sequencing adverbs like 'later', 'next', 'former'. A (temporal) deictic centre. There are ELU threads on 'deixis' you can look up.
